# How can I load a saved JSON tree with treelib?

Tags: python, json, tree

I have made a Python script wherein I process a big html with BeautifulSoup while I build a tree from it using treelib: http://xiaming.me/treelib/.
I have found that this library comes with methods to save the tree file on my system and also parsing it to JSON. But after I do this, how can I load it?
It is not efficient to build the same entire tree for each run. I think I can make a function to parse the JSON tree previously written to a file but I just want to be sure if there exists another easy way or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit an example of the xml, maybe I can give you an example of an json-reader for it.

Comment: Which xml? Do you mean the html from which I create the tree? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The simple Answer

With **this** treelib, you **can't**.

As they say in their documentation (http://xiaming.me/treelib/pyapi.html#node-objects):

```
tree.save2file(filename[, nid[, level[, idhidden[, filter[, key[, reverse]]]]]]])
    Save the tree into file for offline analysis.
```

It does not contain any JSON-Parser, so it can not read the files.

### What can you do?

You have no other option as building the tree each time for every run.

Implement a JSON-Reader that parses the file and creates the tree for you.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 2):

I have built a small parser for my case. Maybe it works in your case.
The note identifiers are named after the tag plus the depth of the node in the tree (tag+depth).

```
import json
from types import prepare_class
from treelib import Node, Tree, node
import os

file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

with open(file_path + '\\tree.json') as f:
    tree_json = json.load(f)

tree = Tree()

def load_tree(json_tree, depth=0, parent=None):
    k, value = list(json_tree.items())[0]
    
    if parent is None:
        tree.create_node(tag=str(k), identifier=str(k)+str(depth))
        parent = tree.get_node(str(k)+str(depth))

    for counter,value in enumerate(json_tree[k]['children']):    
        if isinstance(json_tree[k]['children'][counter], str):
            tree.create_node(tag=value, identifier=value+str(depth), parent=parent)
        else:
            tree.create_node(tag=list(value)[0], identifier=list(value)[0]+str(depth), parent=parent)
            load_tree(json_tree[k]['children'][counter], depth+1, tree.get_node(list(value)[0]+str(depth)) )

load_tree(tree_json)
```

Comment: if json contains arrays: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items' ....

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function to convert json to a tree:

```
from treelib import Node, Tree, node

def create_node(tree, s, counter_byref, verbose, parent_id=None):
    node_id = counter_byref[0]
    if verbose:
        print(f"tree.create_node({s}, {node_id}, parent={parent_id})")
    tree.create_node(s, node_id, parent=parent_id)
    counter_byref[0] += 1
    return node_id

def to_compact_string(o):
    if type(o) == dict:
        if len(o)>1:
            raise Exception()
        k,v =next(iter(o.items()))
        return f'{k}:{to_compact_string(v)}'
    elif type(o) == list:
        if len(o)>1:
            raise Exception()
        return f'[{to_compact_string(next(iter(o)))}]'
    else:
        return str(o)

def to_compact(tree, o, counter_byref, verbose, parent_id):
    try:
        s = to_compact_string(o)
        if verbose:
            print(f"# to_compact({o}) ==> [{s}]")
        create_node(tree, s, counter_byref, verbose, parent_id=parent_id)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def json_2_tree(o , parent_id=None, tree=None, counter_byref=[0], verbose=False, compact_single_dict=False, listsNodeSymbol='+'):
    if tree is None:
        tree = Tree()
        parent_id = create_node(tree, '+', counter_byref, verbose)
    if compact_single_dict and to_compact(tree, o, counter_byref, verbose, parent_id):
        # no need to do more, inserted as a single node
        pass
    elif type(o) == dict:
        for k,v in o.items():
            if compact_single_dict and to_compact(tree, {k:v}, counter_byref, verbose, parent_id):
                # no need to do more, inserted as a single node
                continue
            key_nd_id = create_node(tree, str(k), counter_byref, verbose, parent_id=parent_id)
            if verbose:
                print(f"# json_2_tree({v})")
            json_2_tree(v , parent_id=key_nd_id, tree=tree, counter_byref=counter_byref, verbose=verbose, listsNodeSymbol=listsNodeSymbol, compact_single_dict=compact_single_dict)
    elif type(o) == list:
        if listsNodeSymbol is not None:
            parent_id = create_node(tree, listsNodeSymbol, counter_byref, verbose, parent_id=parent_id)
        for i in o:
            if compact_single_dict and to_compact(tree, i, counter_byref, verbose, parent_id):
                # no need to do more, inserted as a single node
                continue
            if verbose:
                print(f"# json_2_tree({i})")
            json_2_tree(i , parent_id=parent_id, tree=tree, counter_byref=counter_byref, verbose=verbose,listsNodeSymbol=listsNodeSymbol, compact_single_dict=compact_single_dict)
    else: #node
        create_node(tree, str(o), counter_byref, verbose, parent_id=parent_id)
    return tree
```

Then for example:

```
import json
j = json.loads('{"2": 3, "4": [5, 6], "7": {"8": 9}}')
json_2_tree(j ,verbose=False,listsNodeSymbol='+' ).show()
```

gives:

```
+
├── 2
│   └── 3
├── 4
│   └── +
│       ├── 5
│       └── 6
└── 7
    └── 8
        └── 9
```

While

```
json_2_tree(j ,listsNodeSymbol=None, verbose=False ).show()
```

```
+
├── 2
│   └── 3
├── 4
│   ├── 5
│   └── 6
└── 7
    └── 8
        └── 9
```

And

```
json_2_tree(j ,compact_single_dict=True,listsNodeSymbol=None).show()
```

```
+
├── 2:3
├── 4
│   ├── 5
│   └── 6
└── 7:8:9
```

As you see, there are different trees one can make depending on how explicit vs. compact he wants to be.
As you see, there are different trees one can make depending on how explicit vs. compact he wants to be.
One of my favorites, and one of the most compact ones might be using [yaml:](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)

```
import yaml
j = json.loads('{"2": "3", "4": ["5", "6"], "7": {"8": "9"}}')
print(yaml.dump(j, sort_keys=False))
```

Gives **the compact and unambiguous**:

```
'2': '3'
'4':
- '5'
- '6'
'7':
  '8': '9'
```